# Issues using StringBuilder for Speech Recognition. Despite using RecognizeMode Multiple, only detects one word

Tags: speech-recognition

I was bored trying to create another means of online searches for YouTube with some success. I decided to use **StringBuilder** to **AppendLine** my speech, but despite using  **RecognizeMode.Multiple** it will only detect a single word. Basically it takes my speech and writes to file instantly, which is good because you never need to create a command list. A web search launches right after, (all happening in a split second.) It automatically updates itself from each word spoken, replacing the last spoken word. I have tried several other tactics to no avail. I understand Google and Youtube have search engines, but I see no point in using them if you take interest in being a creative programmer. It kind of defeats the purpose of being programmer. I wanted to think outside the box and I am seeking someone to tackle this problem with an open mind. **I wish to avoid** using **Sapi** and **Dictation** for the record. I really want to make this work, and appreciate all the help that can be afforded. I wondered if possibly the sb.ToString()) at the end of the file path may need adjustment somehow? It will execute single word searches with ease. This is the entire code minus the Imports which are all there:

```
Private ReadOnly Drone As New SpeechRecognitionEngine

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If Not Directory.Exists($"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\WM") Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory($"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\WM")
    End If
    'My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory($"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\WM")

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("en-US")

    Drone.LoadGrammarAsync(New Grammar(New GrammarBuilder(New Choices(File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\justin.ross\source\repos\Search Ultima\Search Ultima\ArchiveData.txt")))))
    Drone.RequestRecognizerUpdate()
    Drone.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
    AddHandler Drone.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf Recognizer_SpeechRecognized
    Drone.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)

End Sub

Private Sub Recognizer_SpeechRecognized(sender As Object, e As SpeechRecognizedEventArgs)
    Dim speech As String = e.Result.Text.ToString

    Select Case (speech)
        Case speech

            If speech <> "+" Then
                'This section will take spoken word, write to file then execute search.
                Dim sb As New StringBuilder
                sb.AppendLine(speech)
                File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\justin.ross\source\repos\Search Ultima\Search Ultima\File.txt", sb.ToString())

                speech = "https://www.youtube.com/search?q=" & Uri.EscapeUriString(speech)
                Dim proc As New Process()
                Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(speech)
                proc.StartInfo = startInfo
                proc.Start()

                Return
            End If
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    'Create Event
End Sub

'Disable Engine
Private Sub Disable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Disable.Click
    Drone.RecognizeAsyncStop()
    Dim frm As New ScarlettUltima
    frm.Show()
    Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.informative, AudioPlayMode.Background)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Note: I tried Speech Hypothosized and it caught each word, but opened separate web search windows for each word, instead of creating one phrase for a search.

Comment: If I do use DictationGrammar it works with these two adjustments:  Private ReadOnly Qa As New DictationGrammar &  Drone.LoadGrammarAsync(Qa) and it StringBuilds with AppendLine to the  File.WriteAllText path in phrases verse single as the issue I had without it. If this could be resolved without using DictationGrammar, it would be pretty cool if you are up for the challenge.